# Mutli-level analysis car- and dplyr-

Tags: r, package, regression, longitudinal, multilevel-analysis

library(car) or library(dplyr) packages are showing up with this error code

```
   > library(car)
Error in library(car) : there is no package called ‘car’
> library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
> new&time=recode(new$ind,'"V1"=0;"V2"=1;"V3"=2;"V4"=3;"V5"=4;"V6"=5;',as.factor=F)
Error in recode(new$ind, "\"V1\"=0;\"V2\"=1;\"V3\"=2;\"V4\"=3;\"V5\"=4;\"V6\"=5;",  : 
  could not find function "recode"
```

**I am trying to use the recode function for a longitudinal analysis in R to create a new variable before creating my null model. I am not sure why is cannot find the rate code functions? Is it under a new name?**

Comment: you did not install the package dplyr

Comment: You are right! I was freaking out and overthinking it and missed the first step.